# Rails complex query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a really complex query which joins 4 or 5 tables, and to make it easier, I execute it in 2 steps:

First I obtain the ids using raw sql:

```
annex_ids = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql_str)
```

After that I want the actual objects, with some joins also:

```
@annexes = Annex.includes(:contract, { service_address: {street: :city} }, :billing_address, { contract: [:client] }, :packages).find(annex_ids)
```

But I get the following error message:

Couldn't find all Annexes with IDs ({"id"=>3}, {"id"=>4}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: rather than `find` try using `where(id: annex_ids)`

Comment: what is the output of this query `annex_ids = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql_str)`

Comment: It looks like this: `{"id"=>3}, {"id"=>4}`

Comment: If I change to `find`, I get this error: Cannot visit ActiveRecord::Result

Comment: that's the error it is showing run this `annex_ids = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql_str)` then `annex_ids.collect!{|c| c.values} ` then pass `annex_ids` to your query

Comment: It worked! Thanks! How can I make this an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Couldn't find all Annexes with IDs ({"id"=>3}, {"id"=>4})` this error as find query expecting only `ids` but

```
 annex_ids = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql_str)
```

returning

```
{"id"=>3}, {"id"=>4}
```

So get ids from that, and pass to `find`

```
annex_ids.collect!{|c| c.values}
```

Then pass `annex_ids` to query